# $cordovaKeyboard gone wrong - Ionic Framework, Cordova, ngCordova

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am testing a login view on a Samsung galaxy young pro duos which has its own physical keyboard and Android 2.3.6 version but I can't submit the form when I use `$cordovaKeyboard` in the controller. When I remove `$cordovaKeyboard` the input does not enter any text.

Here is the controller:

```
.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location, $ionicLoading, $cordovaKeyboard) {
$scope.enableBackButton = false;
$scope.loginData = {};
$scope.tryLogin = function(loginData) {
    alert('Test OK');
};})
```

And the view:

```
<ion-view title="HKI-CI Projet Femmes Enceintes" hide-back-button="true">
<div class="bar bar-subheader bar-calm">
    <h2 class="title">IDENTIFICATION</h2>
</div>
<ion-content class="padding has-header has-subheader">
    <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Identifiant" ng-model="loginData.identifiant">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" ng-model="loginData.motDePasse">
        </label>
    </div>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer-bar>
    <div class="button-bar">
        <button class="button button-royal ion-checkmark" ng-click="tryLogin(loginData)"> CONNEXION</button>
    </div>
</ion-footer-bar></ion-view>
```

Maybe I miss something so please help me.

Comment: Is the plugin installed?

Comment: Yes the keyboard plugin is installed